# Use of $unwind and $text in aggregation framework mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongo db say called pages.
In that i have an array of documents called articles.
And in each of those documents in that array i have say an article number and article content.

What i want to do is that unwind the articles and then use $text to search for a word in article Content. But $text has to be in first stage of pipeline.

What happens now if i execute in first stage of pipeline without unwinding is that on first search of text it returns all the remaining articles for that document irrespective of whether it has the text.

Note : Pages collection contains a lot of documents.

Sample Collection :

```
{
   pageNo: 1,
   articles:[{
          articleNo:1,
          articleContent:"cat dog cat dog"
        },{
          articleNo:2,
          articleContent:" Some random text"
        }]
},
{
   pageNo: 2,
   articles:[{
          articleNo:1,
          articleContent:"Some random text"
        },{
          articleNo:2,
          articleContent:"cat dog cat"
        }]
}
```

Expected output: Say i search for "cat"

```
{
   pageNo:1,
    articles:[{
          articleNo:1,
          articleContent:"cat dog cat dog"
        }]
},
{
  pageNo:2,
   articles:[{
          articleNo:2,
          articleContent:"cat dog cat" 
        }]
}
```

Comment: please add example documents and your expected results. Anyway, if you are using `$text` because of a text index, you are right, indexes are used only in the first stage of the pipeline. you can still search after `$unwind` for the text and get the desired results, but it won't use an index. If it is a requirement, change your schema.

Comment: @Tom is this possible index of text is set on articleContent

Comment: It is possible but only in `$match` stage and only when the first stage of aggregation pipeline. So it won't give you the required results. see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below answer will return your desired results. the first `$match` is used only to filter documents without `cat` in it at all, with the help of the `text` index. If you don't use this stage, the results will be the same and correct but may be slower.

```
db.pages.aggregate([
     {
         $match: {
             $text: {
                 $search: "cat"
             }
         } 
     },
     {
         $unwind: '$articles'
     },
     {
         $match: {
             'articles.articleContent': /cat/
         }
     },
     {
         $group: {
             _id: {
                 _id: '$_id',
                 pageNo: '$pageNo'
             },
             articles: {
                 $push: '$articles'
             }
         }
     },
     {
         $project: {
             _id: '$_id._id',
             pageNo: '$_id.pageNo',
             articles: 1
         }
     }
])
```

Comment: Thank you but to make it faster will i have to change the schema by flattening the data structure?

Comment: If you want to use an index and to retrieve only one article, yes, the schema needs to change.