# Mongo text search aggregation for nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document with a nested array of objects with a long list of properties. Instead of searching through the documents, I need a search inside one document's nested data.

(nested properties have indexes like `'data.$**': 'text'`)

***Document item**:*

```
    "_id": "...",
    "data": [
         {
            "name": "Bob"
            ... 
         },
         {
            "name": "Mark" 
            ...
         },
         {
            "name": "John"
            ... 
         }
      ]
    }
```

***Some wrong example of code for explaining what I want*** (cause error `'...$text is only allowed...'`)

```
   const foundData = await this.fileModel
      .aggregate(
        [
          { $unwind: '$data' },
          { $match: { $text: { $search: "Mark" } } },
        ])
      .exec();
```

Without `$unwind` it will work of course but will return whole objects in array.

***Needed result***

```
    "_id": "...",
    "data": [
         {
            "name": "Mark" 
            ...
         }
      ]
    }
```

**P.S**: Solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897504/use-of-unwind-and-text-in-aggregation-framework-mongodb) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410763/nested-object-text-search-in-mongodb) is not ok, since I don't want listed hundreds of properties...